# Docker Hello Wold - oci runtime error

Tags: macos, docker

I am trying to understand Docker and I have a very simple **Dockerfile** at `~/dockerfiles/test` on my OSX.

```
FROM scratch
RUN echo "Hello world" > ~/helloworld.txt
CMD ["cat", "~/helloworld.txt"]
```

When I try to build an image for this file like

```
docker build -t simple .
```

I get an error during the build process.

**Error Output**

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon 2.048 kB
Step 1 : FROM scratch
 ---> 
Step 2 : RUN echo "Hello world" > ~/helloworld.txt
 ---> Running in fc772fd39d45
oci runtime error: exec: "/bin/sh": stat /bin/sh: no such file or directory
```

Any pointers on why I am facing this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You start [from SCRATCH](https://hub.docker.com/_/scratch/) (the empty image), you are using [`cat`, which is not a shell built-in](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/208615/7490).

`cat` needs `/bin/sh` to run (it will fork the process and load dynamic libraries)

---

Note: By default, `ENTRYPOINT` is `/bin/sh -c`, but the doc "[Creating a simple base image using scratch](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/baseimages/#/creating-a-simple-base-image-using-scratch)" shows that `ENTRYPOINT` is empty for a scratch image.

As [BMitch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/596285/bmitch) comments [below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39384840/docker-hello-wold-oci-runtime-error#comment66127848_39385798):

> The quick fix to the problem is changing from to something like `FROM debian:latest` or even `FROM busybox:latest` if size matters

The image currently used for that is **[alpine](https://hub.docker.com/_/alpine/)**

```
FROM alpine:3.4
```

The image is only 5 MB and has access to a package repository that is much more complete than other BusyBox based images.

Comment: The quick fix to the problem is changing from to something like `FROM debian:latest` or even `FROM busybox:latest` if size matters.

Comment: @BMitch Thank you. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility. I would use Alpine.